# Oracle SQL query for following output?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Purchase Table

UserId    Date   Product
----------------------------
usr101    09-08-17  purchase
usr101    09-08-17  purchase
usr102    09-08-17  purchase
usr101    10-08-17  purchase
usr103    10-08-17  Purchase
usr103    10-08-17  Purchase
usr102    11-08-17  purchase
usr104    11-08-17  purchase

User Table

UserId    Name
-----------------
usr101   Fidal
usr102   robert
usr103   Lenin
usr104   Marx
```

I want the following output:

```
name   date        count(purchase)
fidal  09-08-17    2
```

1. I've to count the no of purchase based on `date`.
2. I've to count the no of purchase based on `userid`.

Comment: You know the join condition and that you want an aggregate count, so what is the issue you're facing (and where is your code)? Why do you only want to see that one user and date - what is the logic?

Comment: do you want to only min date?

Comment: No . I want all the user who is made no of purchases on a particular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
     B.name, 
     A.date, 
     count(*)
from 
     purchaseTable A, 
     userTable B 
where 
     A.userId = B.userID 
group by 
     B.name, A.date
```

Comment: Thanks, Psj. It's working great. Can you suggest me how do i practise these kind of problems?

Comment: @S.TATHITHIYAN if you're looking for some decent tutorials and learning materials (free) W3schools ( https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp ) or   tutorialspoint also have prty good ones (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u.Name,
       p.Date,
       count(1)
from purchase_table p
  JOIN user_table u
  ON p.UserId = u.UserId    
group by u.Name,
         p.Date
```

Comment: Which date will be return?

Comment: @mehmet sahin It returns all grouping dates with all user_names